# On facebook SIgnin button im getting the title as Login with Facebook in ios?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

when I sign out the facebook then on sign in button new title is appearing.

After loginto the facebook I signout, then button title is changing to loginwithfacebook.
How can I resolve this.?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't clear in your question that what are you using for face book login like "FacebookLoginCustomUI" or "FacebookLoginUIControll". SO I suggest you a link from where you can get idea for both ways by seeing demo application behaviour.
[Facebook sample apps](https://github.com/facebookarchive/ios-howtos)